# String multiplication versus for loop

Tags: python

I was solving a Python question on CodingBat.com. I wrote following code for a simple problem of printing a string n times-

```
def string_times(str, n):
    return n * str
```

Official result is -

```
def string_times(str, n):
    result = ""
    for i in range(n):
       result = result + str
    return result

print string_times('hello',3)
```

The output is same for both the functions. I am curious how string multiplication (first function) perform against for loop (second function) on performance basis. I mean which one is faster and mostly used?

Also please suggest me a way to get the answer to this question myself (using time.clock() or something like that)

Comment: The party line in Python has always been repeated string concat is inefficient, so the official version is inferior to `"".join(str_repeat for _ in range(n))` anyway.

Comment: Official answer looks more like PASCAL than Python. And what is with the "result = result + str" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use [the `timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to test this:

```
python -m timeit "100*'string'"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.222 usec per loop

python -m timeit "''.join(['string' for _ in range(100)])"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.9 usec per loop

python -m timeit "result = ''" "for i in range(100):" "  result = result + 'string'"
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 usec per loop
```

You can see that multiplying is the far faster option. You can take note that while the string concatenation version isn't that bad in CPython, that [may not be true in other versions of Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation). You should always opt for string multiplication or `str.join()` for this reason - not only but speed, but for readability and conciseness.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is way clear now, I am using Timer from timeit to time my functions now.

Answer (score 4):

I've timed the following three functions:

```
def string_times_1(s, n):
    return s * n

def string_times_2(s, n):
    result = ""
    for i in range(n):
       result = result + s
    return result

def string_times_3(s, n):
    "".join(s for _ in range(n))
```

The results are as follows:

```
In [4]: %timeit string_times_1('hello', 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 262 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit string_times_2('hello', 10)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit string_times_3('hello', 10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.87 us per loop
```

As you can see, `s * n` is not only the clearest and the most concise, it is also the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) stuff from either the command line or in code to see how fast some bit of python code is:

```
$ python -m timeit "\"something\" * 100"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.608 usec per loop
```

Do something similar for your other function and compare.

Comment: Uh, that just defines the function a lot, and why specify the number of loops?

Comment: (1) Teaching how to fish is good, but including the results for this case doesn't hurt and makes the answer more complete. (2) You have to actually call the function and make the `def` the setup, else you're benchmarking function definition. Or even better, do away with the definition and just benchmark the expression `some_str * some_num`. -1 for that, as the answer's currently **wrong**. By the way, why pass `-n`? The default is fine.