# How do I use the .replace() function to change all but the last 4 characters of a string into the # symbol?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to change all but the last four characters in a string to the # symbol on output.
Here's what I have currently

```
>>> v
'0123456789'
>>> for ch in v:
...     if ch in v:
...             v = v.replace(ch, '#')
...
>>> print v
##########
```

As you can see, ALL characters are replaced.

I've tried using all types of index slicing methods but nothing seems to work! I've also tried...

```
>>> v = '0123456789'
>>> for ch in v:
...     if ch in v:
...             v = v[0:-4].replace(ch, '#') + v[-3:]
...
>>> print v
789
```

But, as you can see here, it gets rid of all the other characters.
Please help.

Comment: Before using the suggestions below, I'd also recommend checking the length of the incoming string and use appropriate logic.

Answer (score 5):

Python strings are immutable, so something like this should work. No loops

```
>>> v = '0123456789'
>>> '#'*(len(v) - 4)+v[-4:]
'######6789'
```

The thing about replace is that what if you had `333333` and you `replace('3', '#')`? Everything becomes a `#`, right?

Comment: Yeah. SpoonMeiser clarified my point. The max arg wouldn't be good, because what would you set it to? `len(v)-4`?

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "0123456789"

result = "".join(['#' for x in s[:-4]]) + s[-4:]
```

Comment: String multiplication is faster than iteration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418398/string-multiplication-versus-for-loop

Comment: ah cool! thanks for that! I really need to read up on these little optimisations and start using them more.
cheers for the info!

Answer (score 1):

That's not really what replace is for: a sensible usage is:

```
>>>  'abcbabcba'.replace('ba','zy')
'abczybczy'
```

What you want is best addressed by string indexing with negative subscripting and string duplication

```
assert len(v) >= 4
result = ( '#' * (len(v)-4) ) + v[-4:]
```

Note that assertion. You'll need to code specially for that case if v can ever be shorter than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution by [@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) works just fine if you want to replace all characters, if you want to filter some you can use the approach you used. However, the last part in your new v assignment should be `v[-4:]` rather than `v[-3:]`

Answer (score 0):

The `.replace()` method is not appropriate for what you're trying to do. It replaces all instances of a character with another:

```
>>> '123412341234'.replace('1', '#')
'#234#234#234'
```

So looping through calling replace for each character you find, is pointless.

Instead, just construct a new string from the right number of `#`s and the last 4 digits of the original.

```
'%s%s' % (
    '#' * (len(v) - 4),
    v[-4:]
)
```